# FaunaDB: Query for all documents not referenced by another collection

Tags: faunadb

I'm working on an app where users learn about different patterns of grammar in a language. There are three collections; `users` and `patterns` are interrelated by `progress`, which looks like this:

```js
Create(Collection("progress"), {
  data: {
    userRef: Ref(Collection("users"), userId),
    patternRef: Ref(Collection("patterns"), patternId),
    initiallyLearnedAt: Now(),
    lastReviewedAt: Now(),
    srsLevel: 1
  }
})
```

I've learned how to do some basic Fauna queries, but now I have a somewhat more complex relational one. I want to write an FQL query (and the required indexes) to retrieve *all patterns for which a given user doesn't have progress*. That is, everything they haven't learned yet. How would I compose such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One clarifying assumption - a `progress` document is created when a user starts on a particular pattern and means the user has *some* progress. For example, if there are ten patterns and a user has started two, there will be two documents for that user in `progress`.

If that assumption is valid, your question is "how can we find the other eight?"

The basic approach is:

1. Get all available patterns.
2. Get the patterns a user has worked on.
3. Select the [difference](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/difference?lang=shell) between the two sets.

#### 1. Get all available patterns.

This one is trivial with the built-in [Documents](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/documents?lang=shell) function in FQL:

```
Documents(Collection("patterns"))
```

#### 2. Get the patterns a user has worked on.

To get all the patterns a user has worked on, you'll want to create an index over the `progress` collection, as you've figured out. Your *terms* are what you want to search on, in this case `userRef`. Your *values* are the results you want back, in this case `patternRef`.

This looks like the following:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "patterns_by_user",
  source: Collection("progress"),
  terms: [
    { field: ["data", "userRef"] }
  ],
  values: [
    { field: ["data", "patternRef"] }
  ],
  unique: true
})
```

Then, to get the [set](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/sets?lang=shell) of all the patterns a user has *some* progress against:

```
Match(
  "patterns_by_user",
  Ref(Collections("users"), userId)
)
```

#### 3. Select the difference between the two sets

The FQL function `Difference` has the following signature:

```
Difference( source, diff, ... )
```

This means you'll want the largest set first, in this case all of the documents from the `patterns` collection.

If you reverse the arguments you'll get an empty set, because there are no documents in the set of patterns the user has worked on *that are not also in the set of all patterns*.

From the docs, the return value of `Difference` is:

> When source is a Set Reference, a Set Reference of the items in source that are missing from diff.

This means you'll need to [`Paginate`](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/paginate?lang=shell) over the difference to get the references themselves.

```
Paginate(
  Difference(
    Documents(Collection("patterns")),
    Match(
      "patterns_by_user",
      Ref(Collection("users"), userId)
    )
  )
)
```

From there, you can do what you need to do with the references. As an example, to retrieve all of the data for each returned pattern:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Difference(
      Documents(Collection("patterns")),
      Match(
        "patterns_by_user",
        Ref(Collection("users"), userId)
      )
    )
  ),
  Lambda("patternRef", Get(Var("patternRef")))
)
```

### Consolidated solution

1. Create the index `patterns_by_user` as in step two
2. Query the difference as in step three

Comment: Aha, thank you! I had figured out to use `Difference`, but the key I was missing there was the combination of source+terms+values to make that `patterns_by_user` index. That's extremely useful.